# R: object 'nativeRoutines' not found

Tags: r, travis-ci

Travis-CI fails for my package [coRanking](https://github.com/gdkrmr/coRanking) with "R: devel".
The error message is:

```
Error in nativeRoutines[[lib]] <- routines :
object 'nativeRoutines' not found
```

"R: release" and "R: oldrel" work fine. Did some R internals change or is the "R: devel" on travis currently broken?

I also sent the package to winbuilder and it works fine with R-devel

You can find the travis build here:

https://travis-ci.org/gdkrmr/coRanking/jobs/428661435

Comment: I am experiencing the same error when testing a package with docker and  `rocker/tidyverse:devel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem just fixed itself. It was probably a bug in the particular version of R.

Comment: I think it is actually a problem with an out of date `devtools`. That worked for me.